# Appended HTML5 Video not playing?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to have a video player appear when a button is pressed..

This is how i append my video: (I wrote a script in index.html)

```
$("#videoContainer").append(
                 "<video id=\"video-player\" width=\"100%\" height=\"400\" controls class=\"b-1\">" +
                    "<source src='asset/video/" + materialVideo.episode +".mp4"+"' type=\"video/mp4\">" +
                    "<source src='asset/video/" + materialVideo.episode +".webm"+"' type=\"video/webm\">" + 
                    "<source src='asset/video/" + materialVideo.episode +".ogg"+"' type=\"video/ogg\">" +
                 "</video>"
        );
```

My Folder structure is

```
asset
      video
           file name
js
styles
index.html
```

I already fixed the MIME type and added .mp4 to it. It just shows a blank player with the play/pause button. It doesn't work on both firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you putting "asset" without "s", but the name of folder is "assets".

Comment: Edited. Sorry, it is asset.

Comment: Try to add these attr to the video element:
preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls"
And check the result.

Comment: Sorry it still didn't do anything~

Comment: Did you make sure that the "materialVideo.episode" it return the correct name of the video file?
Can you test the video tag without click event?
Try to put your html video block in your html directly (with static src), and check if the video is working.

Comment: Yes it does, and I also tried directly putting the block to the html, and still doesn't work it returns 403 (Forbidden) error.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

:8080/asset/video/video1.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Your code has folder name as "asset" whereas your Folder Structure says folder name is "assets".
To catch such type of errors, you can always check developer's console of your browser.

Comment: Edited. Sorry, it is asset.